# Uniform distribution random sampling

Tags: r, random, distribution, uniform-distribution

I need to take 10 samples of size 10 from Uniform distribution (a=0,b=1)

I've tried doing runif(10,0,1) but I do not know how to make R take 10 samples at once.

Comment: you dont really need to  use a loop here, just take `nsamples * nrreps` samples and store them in a `nsamples` by `nrreps` matrix e.g. using 5 repetitions for clarity ; `nreps = 5; nsamples = 10; matrix(runif(nreps * nsamples), nrow=nsamples)`, where each column is a different replication

Answer (score 3):

returns a matrix

```
replicate(10, runif(10,0,1))
```

returns a list of 10 vectors

```
lapply(rep(10, 10), function(x) runif(x,0,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`replicate` will call a function `n` number of times.

```
replicate(10, runif(10, 0, 1), simplify = FALSE)
# will return a list; `simplify = TRUE` would return a matrix
```